# Liquibase maven plugin, issue with my database driver

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying use liquibase maven plugin to generate changelog xml file. I add plugin to my pom file like below.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>web/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                <changeLogFile>web/src/main/resources/data/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I am using liquibase.properties:

```
url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/recproject_test? 
useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
username=recproject
password=sample
classpath=/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector- 
java-5.1.38.jar
changeLogFile=web/src/main/resources/data/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.0.xml
```

But when I run liquibase:generateChangeLog as a maven goal I get:

```
Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I store /mysql-connector-java jar in External Libraries and classpath in liquibase.properites is a path to this file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've downloaded `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar` from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38) but it doesn't contain `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.
So you should use database driver `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or [download newer version of driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.12) if you want to use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` .

Answer (score 0):

Add `driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to your properties and if you comparing it to another MySql database then you'll need to also include `referenceDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. It seems like Liquibase will default to the MySQL 8 driver unless you specify both the driver and referenceDriver